# ¿Alinear a la misma altura objetos div inline-block de distintos tamaños?

Tags: html, css

Tengo tres "div" cada uno con diferentes contenido, los cuales quiero que estén centrados y alineadosde la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el que cada cuadro representa cada uno de los div. Pero usando display: inline-block no se acomodan de esa manera. ¿Qué debo de hacer para acomodarlos así?
Otra alternativa podría ser usar float, pero ¿cómo podría centrarlos?

Comment: Utiliza css3 para ello existe ahora display flex.

Comment: para inline `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para elementos`inline-block` se usa `vertical-align:top`

algo asi:

```css
.externo {
  background:#fafafa;
}
ul, .centrado {
  text-align:center;
}
li, .aintlyin {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   width: 50px;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px dashed red;
   background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="externo">
  <h2>con UL</h2>
  <ul class="centrado">
    <li>un item</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
    <li>otro item un poco mas largo</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
    <li>otro item mas largo</li>
    <li>otro item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="externo">
  <h2>con DIV</h2>
  <div class="centrado">
    <div class="aintlyin">un item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item un poco mas largo</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item mas largo</div>
    <div class="aintlyin">otro item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te mencione en el comentario, para ello podrias utilizar una propiedad nueva de CSS3 que se llama `display: flex`, Te dejo un ejemplo acá.

```css
.box {border: 1px solid black}
.row {display: flex}
.col {-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0; flex-basis: 0; -ms-flex-positive: 1; flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box col">HOLA SOY UN DIV 1</div>
  <div class="box col">HOLA SOY UN DIV 2</div>
  <div class="box col">HOLA SOY UN DIV 3</div>
</div>
```