# ¿Cómo colocar section y article? [CSS] [HTML]

Tags: html, css

a ver si podéis echar una mano a un novato. Tengo el siguiente código y necesito hacer lo siguiente:

1. Colocar el section a la derecha del vídeo, alineado superiormente con el y ocupando el  ancho disponible que no ocupe el video. El video tiene un ancho especificado de 300px. El ancho de body no está especificado.
2. Dentro del article de la section, colocar el span a la derecha de la imagen haciendo que span e imagen estén alineados superiormente.

   ```
    <html>

    <head>

     <title>Prueba</title>

   </head>

   <body>

    <video width="300" height="250" controls poster="prueba-poster.jpg ">
           <source src="prueba.mp4 " type="video/mp4 ">       
       </video>

   <section>
       <article>
           <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
           <img src="prueba.jpg ">
           <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa 
            modi quibusdam nesciunt veritatis error quis dignissimos 
            suscipit</span>
           <a href="# ">Ver más</a>
            </article>
          </section>
        </body>
   </html>
   ```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, he probado con float, display:table y vertical-align y aunque creo que los tiros van por ahí, no acabo de ver como lograrlo. Gracias, un saludo! ;)

Comment: El error es que no hay ningún video en tu ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: arreglado, estaba mal insertado el código. gracias @alacnfcm ;)

Comment: cual sería la relación semántica del vídeo respecto del artículo (`<article>`)? y de la sección (`<section>`)? hay mas secciones? algo antes o algo después del par video+section?

Comment: lo de la relación es para ver si englobas todo en un `<main>` y el video como `<aside>`. o si lo metes dentro de `<section>`, un `<div>` también vale. luego `display:inline-block` con `vertical-align:top` (y el implícito `text-align:left`) haría que se acomode

Comment: el video está fuera de section y no guardan relación. va todo como en el código pero podría usar div para agrupar elementos en caso de que eso facilite la tarea...gracias

Answer (score 1):

3 opciones, la primera es con `display:flex` en un contenedor, la segunda explora el por qué usando float no quedan a la misma altura, la tercera es con `display:inline-block` y unos misteriosos 4px extra.

1. Podes usar flex, algo así:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

video {
  background: yellow;
}

section {
  background: green;
}

section img {
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Prueba</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <aside>
      <video width="300" height="250" controls poster="https://picsum.photos/300/250/">
        <source src="prueba.mp4 " type="video/mp4 ">       
    </video>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <article>
        <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100/">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa 
         modi quibusdam nesciunt veritatis error quis dignissimos 
         suscipit</span>
        <a href="# ">Ver más</a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

2. Para usar `float:left;` en el `video` hay dos opciones:

   - calcular el ancho del `section` y darle float
   - sólo darle ancho `auto` y `overflow:hidden` al `section`

```css
.row {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

section.uno {
  background: green;
  width: calc( 100% - 300px);
  float: left;
}

section.dos {
  background: yellow;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section img {
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <video width="300" height="250" controls poster="https://picsum.photos/300/250/">
        <source src="prueba.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <section class="uno">
      <article>
        <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/120/150/">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa 
         modi quibusdam nesciunt veritatis error quis dignissimos 
         suscipit</span>
        <a href="# ">Ver más</a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <video width="300" height="250" controls poster="https://picsum.photos/300/250/">
        <source src="prueba.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <section class="dos">
      <article>
        <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/120/150/">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa 
         modi quibusdam nesciunt veritatis error quis dignissimos 
         suscipit</span>
        <a href="# ">Ver más</a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

3. La idea sugerida en el comentario de usar `inline-block` y `vertical-align:top` como en [¿Alinear a la misma altura objetos div inline-block de distintos tamaños?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176857/alinear-a-la-misma-altura-objetos-div-inline-block-de-distintos-tama%C3%B1os/176863#176863)

   no resulta porque se agregan `4px` (?) entre el `aside` y el `section`, si los restamos en el calc funciona:

```css
aside,
section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  width: 300px;
}

section {
  width: calc(100% - 300px - 4px);
}

section img {
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Prueba</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <aside>
      <video width="300" height="250" controls poster="https://picsum.photos/300/250/">
        <source src="prueba.mp4 " type="video/mp4 ">       
    </video>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <article>
        <h4>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h4>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100/">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa 
         modi quibusdam nesciunt veritatis error quis dignissimos 
         suscipit</span>
        <a href="# ">Ver más</a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```